# ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to use my action bar and i got this execption

```
   08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.ActionProvider
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:374)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:160)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage.onCreateOptionsMenu(AddWorkOutPage.java:3190)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:460)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:822)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:253)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-08 00:54:08.913: E/AndroidRuntime(18468):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have read about this error and its something with my java paths.

I tried all kinds of solutins but i still got this error.

Here is my java path order and export:

[image]

My codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/save_wotkout_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> 

<item android:id="@+id/delete_workout_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> 

<item android:id="@+id/search_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/> 

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="share"/>

</menu>
```

Where the exception is:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_workout_actionbar, menu);

            MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
            mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)
                    MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());

            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
```

Thank for helping

Comment: Did u declare the member `mShareActionProvider` as a `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` ?

Answer (score 1):

Android Design [Adding a Action Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom namespace and use that namespace for the `showAsAction` and `ActionProviderClass` attributes, as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlsns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/save_wotkout_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> 

<item android:id="@+id/delete_workout_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/> 

<item android:id="@+id/search_ab"
    android:title="Add Item"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/> 

    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    myapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="share"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.ActionProvider
```

You decided not to provide any code, so it is difficult to help you much. However, on line 3190 of `AddWorkOutPage.java`, you are attempting to convert an `android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider` into an `android.view.ActionProvider`. That will not work. My guess is that you chose the wrong import, and have imported `android.view.ActionProvider` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.ActionProvider`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. please see my edit :).
I checked and import android.support.v7.widget.ActionProvider

Comment: @dasdasd: Try changing your import of `android.view.ActionProvider` to `android.support.v7.widget.ActionProvider`, as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: i have imported only `android.support.v7.widget.ActionProvider`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the Searchview - android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
and not the v4 library